# How to get the integer and fractional part of a decimal number as two integers in Arduino or C?

Tags: c, integer, arduino

How do I convert 30.8365146 into two integers, 30 and 8365146, for example, in Arduino or C?

This problem faces me when I try to send [GPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) data via [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) series 1 which don't allow to transmit fraction numbers, so I decided to split the data into two parts. How can I do this?

I have tried something like this:

```
double num=30.233;
int a,b;

a = floor(num); 
b = (num-a) * pow(10,3);
```

The output is `30` and `232`! The output is not 30 and 233. Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: How do you intend to maintain the scale of the decimal part?  3.1 and  3.0001 would both come out to be 3 and 1.

Comment: Nice question but i don't know the answer , do u have any suggestion

Comment: You need to define how many decimal places you require - if it is 7 digits, for example, then `.1` would be `1000000` while `.0001` would be `1000`

Comment: XBee transmits data as bytes, effectively a serial link. So it can be whatever format you like. I'd either suggest degrees, minutes and seconds if raw values are used, or write it using a common serial format - http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#position - which GPS software on your pc may well understand directly if you configure the XBee explorer as a serial input.

Answer (score 3):

```
double value = 30.8365146;
int left_part, right_part;
char buffer[50];
sprintf(buffer, "%lf", value);
sscanf(buffer, "%d.%d", &left_part, &right_part);
```

and you will get left/right parts separately stored in integers.

P.S. the other solution is to just multiply your number by some power of 10 and send as an integer.

Comment: thanks alot for your help , but what is the function of the buffer array

Comment: its function is to temporarily keep the value of your variable as a string to be read then by sscanf.

Comment: You need to be a bit wary of this approach. On my compiler using %lf with value results in 30.8365.  If you specify the precession, say %2.10lf you will get something like 30.8365146000 and then you have 2 problems, the number is to big for an int and you have unwanted trailing zeros.

Comment: there is a problem with the code i don't know the reason but when i set value=30.8365  the result is 10218 and 18457 !!!!

Comment: As in the comments, this would fail for all fractional numbers under 1/10.

Comment: If the overflow is the problem, why you don't just send a string (I hope you can send strings), and then do sscanf(received_string, "%lf", &some_double_variable); ?

Answer (score 2):

You can output the integer to a char array using sprintf, then replace the `'.'` with a space and read back two integers using sscanf.

Answer (score 1):

I did it for float, using double as temporary:

```
int fract(float raw) {

    static int digits = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 - std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10 - 1;
    float intpart;
    double fract = static_cast<double>(modf(raw, &intpart));
    fract = fract*pow(10, digits - 1);
    return floor(fract);
}
```

I imagine that you could use quadruple-precision floating-point format to achieve the same for double: [libquadmath](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/Typedef-and-constants.html#Typedef-and-constants).

Answer (score 0):

The 30 can just be extracted by rounding down (floor(x) in math.h).

The numbers behind the decimal point are a bit more tricky, since the number is most likely stored as a binary number internally, this might not translate nicely into the number you're looking for, especially if floating point-math is involved. You're best bet would probably be to convert the number to a string, and then extract the data from that string.

Comment: xbee cant sent a string it can only send characters  so it would be too slow to sent the fraction part as characters

Comment: The string would only be used to convert the binary data to a decimal representation. You then extract the data from this string as integers and sent those. aram90 has given a code example of how to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments, you need to keep track of the decimal places. You can't do a direct conversion to integer. A bit of code that would do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PLACES 3

void extract(double x)
{
        char buf[PLACES+10];
        int a, b;

        sprintf(buf, "%.*f", PLACES, x);
        sscanf(buf, "%d.%d", &a, &b);

        int n = (int) pow(10, PLACES);

        printf("Number           : %.*f\n", PLACES, x);
        printf("  Integer        : %d\n", a);
        printf("  Fractional part: %d over %d\n", b, n);
}

int main()
{
        extract(1.1128);
        extract(20.0);
        extract(300.000512);
}
```

Produces:

```
Number           : 1.113
  Integer        : 1
  Fractional part: 113 over 1000
Number           : 20.000
  Integer        : 20
  Fractional part: 0 over 1000
Number           : 300.001
  Integer        : 300
  Fractional part: 1 over 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using floor() to get the integer value and
num % 1 (modulo arithmetic) to get the decimal component?

Then you could multiply the decimal component by a multiple of 10 and round. 
This would also give you control over how many decimal places you send, if that is limited in your comm. standard.

Would that work?

```
#include <math.h>

integer_part = floor(num); 
decimal_part = fmod(num,1)*10^whatever;
```

Comment: Series1_Tx:85: error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'int' to binary 'operator^' it gives me this error

Comment: I meant that you could use 1000 as 10^3. If you want to do exactly what I wrote, you could do `pow(10,3)`.